# specify default character set for oracle tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How do we specify default character set for oracle tables. In mysql, the following statement does the trick -

`CREATE TABLE if not exists table1 (name varchar(20) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

What will be the equivalent statement in oracle?

Comment: SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS

Answer (score 1):

The characterset is set at database creation time. The `AL32UTF8` is the default characterset for an Oracle database. You can check your character set by:

```
 select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%';
```

or

```
 select * from nls_database_parameters
    where parameter like'%CHARACTERSET%';
```

or

```
SELECT name, value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name like '%CHARACTERSET%' ;
```